# multi row update using cursors PL SQL anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, rdbms

How to we write a PL SQL block for updating multiple rows at a time. The scenarios is, there are two tables `TABLE1,TABLE2` both have a common column  `COLUMN1`. In the anonymous block the cursor is defined on the `TABLE1`.

On running the block for the first time i.e with `v_run:=1` and `v_offset:=2` ,the first two rows will be in cursor. On running the block for the second time   `v_run:=2` and next two rows from `TABLE1` will be in the cursor and so on.

What should be `v_SPECIAL_VARIABLE` in the sample code be so that 
on the first run i.e `v_run:=1`, first two rows(row no 1,2) are fetched in the cursor and their corresponding `COLUMN2` values in `TABLE2` are updated to `'N'` and the rest of the rows in `TABLE2` are updated to `'n'`.

On the second run i.e `v_run:=2`  next two rows (row no 3,4) are fetched from the `TABLE1` in the cursor and their corresponding `COLUMN2` values in `TABLE2` are updated to `'N'` and the rest of the rows in `TABLE2` are updated to `'n'`.

On the third run i.e `v_run:=3`  next two rows (row no 5,6) are fetched from the `TABLE1` in the cursor and their corresponding `COLUMN2` values in `TABLE2` are updated to `'N'` and the rest of the rows in `TABLE2` are updated to `'n'`.

Table1 contains

```
id | COLUMN1     | total
-------------------------
 1 | 1256480     | 5
 2 | 1256481     | 3
 3 | 1256482     | 2
 4 | 1256483     | 1
 5 | 1256484     | 3
 6 | 1256485     | 2
 7 | 1256486     | 1
 8 | 1256487     | 3
```

Table2 contains

```
   | COLUMN1     | column2
-------------------------
  | 1256480     | N
  | 1256481     | N
  | 1256482     | N
  | 1256483     | N
  | 1256484     | N
  | 1256485     | n
  | 1256486     | n
  | 1256487     | n
```

Sample code

```
declare
v_offset number:=2;
v_run    number:=1;
cursor curv1 is
select column1 from 
(select rownum rowcol,column1 from table1)
where rowcol between (v_run-1)*v_offset+1 and v_offset*v_run;
begin

open curv1 ;
fetch curv1 into v_SPECIAL_VARIABLE
----- first update
update table2 set column2='N' where
column1=(' ALL the values in v_SPECIAL_VARIABLE');
----- second update
update table2 set column2='n' where
column1 not in (' ALL the values in v_SPECIAL_VARIABLE');
close curv1 ;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating a cursor and updating on a row-by-row basis is a recipe for poor performance. Get rid of cursors whenever possible, as in:

```
declare
  v_offset number:=2;
  v_run    number:=1;
begin
  -- First update

  UPDATE TABLE2
    SET COLUMN2 = 'N'
    WHERE COLUMN1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1
                        FROM TABLE1
                        WHERE ROWCOL BETWEEN (v_run-1)*v_offset+1
                                         AND v_offset*v_run);

  -- Second update

  UPDATE TABLE2
    SET COLUMN2 = 'n'
    WHERE COLUMN1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1
                            FROM TABLE1
                            WHERE ROWCOL BETWEEN (v_run-1)*v_offset+1
                                             AND v_offset*v_run);
end;
```

Note that in this case the updates could be simplified to:

```
declare
  v_offset number:=2;
  v_run    number:=1;
begin
  -- Second update

  UPDATE TABLE2
    SET COLUMN2 = 'n'
    WHERE COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL;

  UPDATE TABLE2
    SET COLUMN2 = 'N'
    WHERE COLUMN1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1
                        FROM TABLE1
                        WHERE ROWCOL BETWEEN (v_run-1)*v_offset+1
                                         AND v_offset*v_run);
end;
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Cursors are designed to be processed one row at a time. If you want a collection of values, [use a collection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005), not a cursor.

Have you considered doing it without cursors or multiple statements?

```
declare
  v_offset number:=2;
  v_run    number:=1;
begin

  -- one update
  update table2 set column2= CASE WHEN 
    rowcol between (v_run-1)*v_offset+1 and v_offset*v_run
    THEN 'N' ELSE 'n' END
  ;

end;
```

If performance is an issue you'll also want to add a `where` clause to only update the necessary 4 rows each time, instead of all rows in the table.

Comment: Thank for pointing out cursors are for processing one row at a time. I thought there could be collection object that would act like a table and allow to update multiple rows at a time